# Separate data in one field, that is referenced in another field within same table

Tags: sql, database-design

As you can probably guess by how my question has been phrased, I don't have huge SQL skills.

We have a new database, that has a table with all of the 'answers' in one field.  We then have another field within the same table that has the identifier for the 'answer' field.  What I want to do is create a separate field for each answer based on the identifier.

An example of the data is:

```
IDENTIFIER         ANSWER
property type      House
vehicle            Car
property type      Bungalow
property type      House
vehicle            Van
```

What I would like is:

```
VEHICLE         PROPERTY TYPE
car             House
van             Bungalow
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Since you want both vehicles and properties on the same row, how are they related to each other? (I.e. why car with house, and not car with bungalow?) What if the new property cabin shows up?

Comment: Apologies, I knew I wouldn't explain it very well.  All of the identifiers are associated with a incident number. So if I query the incident number, I will get House and Car in the same field but different rows.  I'm looking for them to be on the same row in different fields

Comment: Can't you add this incident number to the sample data above?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see how your property types and vehicles are connected to be in a same row ... this is a best i could do, if you can explain us based on what you are putting them in same row, I could maybe change this query

But this is what i got so far ...

```
Create table #TempTest (Identifier nvarchar(100), Answer nvarchar(100))

insert into #TempTest (Identifier, Answer)
values
('property type',      'House'),
('vehicle',            'Car'),
('property type',      'Bungalow'),
('property type',      'House'),
('vehicle',            'Van')

Select distinct ISNULL([property type],'') [property type],
            ISNULL([vehicle],'') [vehicle]
   from (
      select Row_Number() over (order by [identifier], [Answer]) as 'RowNum',  identifier, Answer from #TempTest
   ) src
PIVOT
(
     MAX(Answer) for identifier IN ([property type],[vehicle])
) piv1
```

It will give you results like this:

```
  property type      vehicle
                      Car
                      Van
    Bungalow    
     House
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a routine design pattern.  Some literature calls it recursive references and other literature calls it reflexive references.

Foreign keys represent relationships, in the ER sense of the word.  A foreign key that references a different row in the same table just represents a relationship between two instances of the same entity.

Example:  relationship between employee and supervisor, another employee.